# Merging HTML files in Java

Tags: java, html

I want to merge multiple HTML files into one. For example, if I have two HTML files which prints `WELCOME` and  `XYZ` respectively, can i merge these two file into one which can show together `WELCOME XYZ`? These operation I want to do for multiple, suppose 1500, files.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you trying to merge the 1500 files together ?

Comment: @nabanitaDasgupta please do not SHOUT.

Comment: Sorry as a new user i DInt know it

Comment: You didnt know that you shouldn't shout ? :P  Check this library [HtmlParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

You might use an HTML parsing/manipulation API such as [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: NO ACTUALLY I HAD TWO HTML FILES WHICH DOES NOT CONTAIN ANY OTHER PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE . I JUST WANT TO MERGE IT INTO ONE USING JAVA OR HTML.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : I think he is not shouting, he just wrote in CAPS... be calm... Even he replied to me in CAPS... :D

Comment: Sorry as I am a new  user I dint know it

Comment: JSoup is an API written in Java.  I used it recently to help transform some HTML to include menus and style sheets etc.

Comment: Could it done using the *built-in* HTML (and XML) parsing API in Java? (I mean the `javax.xml.parsers` and `org.w3c.dom` packages.)

Comment: @ambigram_maker HTML != XML.  Further, Java's inbuilt parsing for XML does not tolerate any errors in the data.  JSoup is an API that specializes into turning the 'tag soup' that most pages consist of, back into a logical structure.  So .. no, not really.

Comment: Never mind. BTW, the `NodeList` and `NamedNodeMap` (in the *built-in* packages) ***do not*** support streams or at least the *for-each* construct. This causes no end to the programmers' misery. :-(

Answer (score 1):

create one html file and keep on including several files using below command...

```
<!--#include virtual="insertthisfile1.html" -->
<!--#include virtual="insertthisfile2.html" -->
<!--#include virtual="insertthisfile3.html" -->
<!--#include virtual="insertthisfile4.html" -->
```

Comment: see my updated answer... Never ever write in CAPS.. Officially it is like SHOUTING on someone... I believe you was not knowing of that.. Right??

Comment: If two HTML files is not in similar format will the method work?

Comment: what you mean by `not similar format`?? try and see what happen if you add different type of files??

Comment: *"please write everything in lower case letters"*  Ughh.. that is almost as bad as all upper case.  It reads like 'mumbling'.  Best approach is to make an upper case letter for these things.  1) The first word of every sentence. 2) Every occurrence of the word 'I' 3) Abbreviations like HTML, JSP etc. 4) Class names like `JFrame`.

Comment: i meant in DAILY LIFE... NOT in JAVA programs... OK??

Answer (score -1):

You can get this done by iterating over all your files and appending the contents of `<body>...</body>` tag together programmatically.

1. Get all the html file names in to an `ArrayList<String>`
2. Create one `StringBuilder`
3. Read each HTML file line by line till you find a line with the body tag
4. Read from that tag start till you find a line with the body tag closing
5. Append this content to the `StringBuilder`
6. After all files are read, write the `StringBuilder` content to one file.

At the end you will have the one single HTML file